# The function minimizing distance between the convex set and a point is convex.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Show that the function $f(x) = \min_{y \in K} \|x-y\|^2$ for a convex set $K$ is a convex function.

I'm unsure how to approach this question. I understand that I need to use the fact that a function is convex if $\forall x,y$ and $\forall \lambda \in [0,1]$, $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1 - \lambda) f(y)$.

Comment: This is not difficult, what have you tried ?

Comment: The minimum should be replaced with infimum. Indeed, if $K$ is not compact, the minimum could not be attained.

Comment: What I thought was I could try different cases. So I picked two points inside the convex set and so the function would return as 0, meaning the above statement is true. Also if one point is inside and the other outside, then the linear combination of the points would result in smaller distance as $\lambda$ gets smaller if $y \in K$. So the above statement is still true. I wasn't quite sure what to say for the last case when both points were outside the convex set.